# in TF2, how do you save models/weights when not using the tf.keras API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In the documentation it seems they focus on how to save and restore tf.keras.models, but i was wondering how do you save and restore models trained customly through some basic iteration loop?

Now that there isnt a graph or a session, how do we save structure defined in a tf function that is customly built without using layer abstractions?

Comment: You can use SavedModel. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/saved_model)

Comment: It's a pity how stupid the documentation is, in both keras and tensorflow saving tutorials, they've written stuff just on Keras.

Comment: caissalover, and the situation hasn't changed... 2022!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a similar way you are used to in Tensorflow 1.x - by using a checkpoint object and, news introduced in Tensorflow 2.0, a checkpoint manager.

```py
ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(step=tf.Variable(1), optimizer=opt, net=net)
manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, './tf_ckpts', max_to_keep=3)
ckpt.restore(manager.latest_checkpoint)
if manager.latest_checkpoint:
  print("Restored from {}".format(manager.latest_checkpoint))
else:
  print("Initializing from scratch.")

for example in toy_dataset():
  loss = train_step(net, example, opt)
```

You can give a look at the [Training checkpoints guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/checkpoints)

Comment: the url leads to a 404 ..please update ..im dying to find out how to do this without using keras

Comment: Maybe this is the new location: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint?hl=en

Comment: thanks ..had gone through this and had to post a query myself , here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71028428/access-intermediate-layer-output-tensorflow